# Changing a Page Component (Rich Text) in SiteCore

Tags: sitecore

[I have managed to create my own style of navigation bar in Sitecore but can't figure out how to extend the width of the Rich Text Page Component I've had to use to input the HTML. Any suggestions on this so I can make my 'buttons' fit on one row?!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VguGC.png)

I'm truely stuck! We have restricted access to editing so what you see is what I have.

Comment: Can you rewrite your question and add some details like markup and CSS? If you have an image, just add it instead of linking three lines of text to it.

Answer (score 0):

What version are you running? If you look at a vanilla installation of Sitecore and apply that customization you'll see the command row will widen as needed. I've just done this in a test environment and do not see your issue. I recommend removing any custom css applied to the site as it can cause unexpected behaviour at times.

Comment: It's Sitecore XP? But I don't think I even have the option to see if there's any custom ccs applied to the site etc as its so restricted.

Comment: What you can do is right click on the bar and inspect it. Look at the styling applied to it and find what is restricting its width, since it's supposed to expand horizontally. When you find that item, see what file it's coming from and that will tell you the cause of the problem. Sometimes the site's custom styling interferes with the editing experience in Sitecore.

Comment: This seems more like a comment and suggestion than an answer though the question really isn't clear